# No Module Named 'exifread'

Tags: exifread

I'm trying to create a python script that pulls directional information from photo attachments in a  FGDB. I've downloaded the exifread module using pip, but I'm still getting the 'No module named 'exifread'' error whenever I try to run my code. I believe there could be an error with versioning between the version of exifread I installed and my version of python.

Has anyone figured out how to install the exifread module that works with Arcgis Pro?

Comment: How did you tell Arcgis Pro to use the Python environment of your system where you probably installed `exifread`?

Answer (score 0):

Pip probably installed exifread to a different version of Python than the version ArcGIS Pro uses.  The Python version that installs with ArcGIS Pro is a walled garden.  You cannot install third-party libraries to that version of Python unless they are ESRI authorized and preinstalled with Pro.  You can [clone your Python environment](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/get-started/work-with-python-environments.htm) (create a new version of Python) on your computer and use that cloned environment to install third-party packages.

These ArcGIS Pro Python versions come preinstalled with the conda installer.  Best to stick with conda for installing rather than pip to avoid conflicting library versions in any cloned versions you may create.

I see that the default version of Pro Python includes [pillow-simd](https://github.com/uploadcare/pillow-simd) (a fork of Pilllow).  Pillow, and PIL in the 2.7 days was capable of reading EXIF data.  Maybe investigate the exif reading powers of pillow-simd.  [Here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764932/in-python-how-do-i-read-the-exif-data-for-an-image) to get you started. This will save you a lot of hassles having to have IT clone your Python environment and recloning it when they have to reset your roaming Windows profile.